# Angular 4: How to create reusable module with component - bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create angular ui-component, and use it in other angular applications.

I met many problem with angular-cli and decided to get rid it from my project, since it is not ready for building library. 
I tried to use webpack, but had a problem with building d.ts bundle(I used dts-bundle, but it can't build bundle with all imports well).

When I created d.ts bundle manually, I realized that project which use webpack don't work correctly with bundly already built by webpack (a lot of errors with third party, module resolution, polyfills).

When I build project with typescript, it worked well, by angular templated (app.component.html), which I don't want to include in my package.
The best way, I think, manage to use something like angular-template-loader
 with typescribt compiler, but I don't know how.

May be there is better approach for it, but I read a lot of topics and have't figured it yet. 
Thank you.

Comment: I found this article helpful... 
http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/

Comment: Here's another article: https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464